# JPanel - GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've currently created the GridLayout:
It's got 4 columns, first two are progress bars, the other two start/stop buttons.
How can I get the last two buttons to be next to eachother?

How I want it:
PROGRESS BAR
PROGRESS BAR
START       STOP

How it is:
PROGRESS BAR
PROGRESS BAR
START
STOP

Even if I change the layout to:
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 3, 3));
It doesn't work, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the two `JProgressBar`s to a `JPanel say centerPanel` with `BridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5)`.

And put the 2 `JButton`s `START and STOP` to another `JPanel say buttonPanel` with Layout i.e. `FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5)` (This will align the `JButton` START with the left side of the `JProgressBar`s, though if you want the `JButton`s to come somewhere in the middle of the same, then simply don't use <del>`setLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5)`</del>. The default Layout for the `JPanel` will do).

Now add `centerPanel` to the `JFrame` using

```
frameReference.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)
```

and add `buttonPanel` using

```
frameReference.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END)
```

That will do :-)

### EDIT 1 :

use a `Border` for this thingy. Like

```
centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK))
```

That will create a `Box` around the `centerPanel`. Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17876938/1057230), though I am using `TitledBorder` in this example.

Comment: Thanks :) I had to edit it a little, but I got it working. Is it possible to group everything? For example have a box surrounding the two progress bars and buttons so it's separated from everything else?